# Count with total by category-wise in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count

I am trying to get category wise total of scholars. I use the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LOGINID,
    ISNULL(SUM(PHD_INTERNAL),0) AS PHD_INTERNAL,
    ISNULL(SUM(MS_INTERNAL),0)  AS MS_INTERNAL,
    ISNULL(SUM(PHD_EXTERNAL),0) AS PHD_EXTERNAL,
    ISNULL(SUM(MS_EXTERNAL),0)  AS MS_EXTERNAL,
    ISNULL((ISNULL(SUM(PHD_INTERNAL), 0)) + (ISNULL(SUM(MS_INTERNAL), 0)) + (ISNULL(SUM(PHD_EXTERNAL), 0)) + (ISNULL(SUM(MS_EXTERNAL),0)),0) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         LOGINID,
         STYPE, CTYPE,
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'Internal' AND CTYPE  = 'Ph.D'
                THEN CNT
         END PHD_INTERNAL,
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'Internal' AND CTYPE  = 'M.S'
                THEN CNT
         END MS_INTERNAL,
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'External' AND CTYPE  = 'Ph.D'
                THEN CNT
         END PHD_ExTERNAL,
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'External' AND CTYPE  = 'M.S'
                THEN CNT
         END MS_EXTERNAL
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
             LOGINID,
             STYPE, CTYPE,
             COUNT (STYPE) AS CNT
         FROM
             SCHDET
         GROUP BY
             LOGINID, STYPE, CTYPE) T
     ) TT
GROUP BY
    LOGINID

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Total',
    ISNULL(SUM(IP), 0) AS IP,
    ISNULL(SUM(IMS), 0) AS IMS,
    ISNULL(SUM(EP), 0) AS EP,
    ISNULL(SUM(EMS), 0) AS EMS,
    ISNULL((ISNULL(SUM(IP), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(IMS), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(EP), 0) + ISNULL(SUM(EMS), 0)), 0) AS TOTAL
FROM
    (SELECT
         'TOTAL',
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'Internal' AND CTYPE  = 'Ph.D'
                THEN CNT
         END IP,
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'External' AND CTYPE  = 'Ph.D'
                THEN CNT
         END EP,
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'Internal' AND CTYPE  = 'M.S'
                THEN CNT
         END IMS,
         CASE
             WHEN STYPE = 'External' AND CTYPE  = 'M.S'
                THEN CNT
         END EMS
     FROM
         (SELECT
              STYPE, CTYPE, COUNT (STYPE) CNT
          FROM
              SCHDET
          GROUP BY
              STYPE, CTYPE) B
     ) BB
GROUP BY
    'Total';
```

But, I'm getting an error:

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 'BB'.

Please help me.

Comment: Edit your question. Add more information. Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

In the view 'BB' you need to define the name of the column which values are 'TOTAL'.

```
.....
FROM
  (
    SELECT 'TOTAL' AS TOTAL,
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Always inner query should have a alias name to use it in outer query.

```
select 'Total' as Total,
```